# upload GCS file to specific service via Curl

Tags: linux, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have file in cloud storage bucket `gs://myfile/test.xlsx`

I would like to create a curl command which post this file into a service like the following

```
curl -F "file=@gs://myfile/test.xlsx" https://myservice/Service/extraction
```

This command works fine with a local file but it doesn't work when I use a file located in GCS

Comment: Once you use the correct hostname format, are you using a signed policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Try to create a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for the object, for you to be able access it in `curl` without using authentication. To create a signed URL that can get an object from a bucket, you need a service account and run the command `gsutil signurl`, for example:

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m key.json gs://myfile/test.xlsx
```

- `10m` is the duration of generated signed URL of object
- `key.json` is name of private key of existing service account

Use the produced signed URL from the command where the string beginning is : `https://storage.googleapis.com` then try it with `curl` command:

```
curl -F "[signedurl]" https://myservice/Service/extraction
```

Comment: By itself, your command will not work. This requires a signed policy as well.

Comment: Thank @JohnHanley! I'll update my answer.